# ScrollListener не работает в Android API15

Tags: java, android, прокрутка

Подскажите в чем причина конструкция

```
relLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener()
```

не работает на API 15 (на более младших API не проверял)
На более поздних версиях всё работает нормально.

Comment: Поясните "не работает".

Comment: имеется ввиде, что при скролле в более поздних версиях выполняется код в onScrollChanged(), а в API15 ничего не происходит

Comment: @f1n, а что пишет? Выдаёт ли какую-либо ошибку?

Comment: нет, ничего, просто не работает. у меня 1 скролл привязан к другому и    я через scrollTo в обработчике передаю от одного другому координаты, так чтобы они прокручивались вместе. Это отлично работает, но в API 15 они прокручиваются не зависимо друг от друга, т. е. координаты не передаются и когда скролишь один второй стоит на месте =))